# How can I specify a React element in the parent that should be looped over in a child's JSX template?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS at the moment and I am struggling with the concept of defining a reusable outer component that consists of children but can be given a child element that should replace its default contents.

In essence, I want to understand how to compose a child's content from the parents tag.

```
<MyContainer1>
    // Uses default, row markup.
    <Table />
</MyContainer1>

<MyContainer2>
    <Table>
        // Replaces only the internal row markup but not the full template that comes with <Table />
        <MySpecialRow />
    </Table>
</MyContainer2>
```

I've mocked up a full JSBin example [here](https://jsbin.com/momuvo/3/edit?js,output) and will put the runnable code below.

```js
class MyTableContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      title: 'My example',
      headers: [
        'Col 1', 'Col 2'
      ],
      rows: [
        { text: 'Row 1', area: 'Area 1' },
        { text: 'Row 2', area: 'Area 2' },
        { text: 'Row 3', area: 'Area 3' },
        { text: 'Row 4', area: 'Area 4' },
      ]
    };
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
        <Table
          headers={this.state.headers}
          rows={this.state.rows} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) { super(props); }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {this.props.headers.map( (header) => {
             return <th key={header}>{header}</th>;
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.rows.map( (row, i) => <Row key={i} text={row.text} area={row.area} /> )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) { super(props); }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.text}</td>
        <td>{this.props.area}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

// A different container rendering a table with a special row of markup
// The <MySpecialRow> should be run in <Table> loop of rows and be given the row's props.
// In addition to that it should now be able to handle the given 'actOnArea' function
// from <MyTableContainer2>.
class MyTableContainer2 extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      title: 'My example 2',
      headers: [
        'Col 1', 'Col 2'
      ],
      rows: [
        { text: 'Row 1', area: 'Area 1' },
        { text: 'Row 2', area: 'Area 2' },
        { text: 'Row 3', area: 'Area 3' },
        { text: 'Row 4', area: 'Area 4' },
      ]
    };
    
  }
  
  actOnArea (area, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Send some people to', area);
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
        <Table
          headers={this.state.headers}
          rows={this.state.rows}>
      
          <MySpecialRow actOnArea={this.actOnArea} />
      
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// Should be swappable and if given as a child of <Table> should be used instead of
// the default <Row>
class MySpecialRow extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) { super(props); }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.text}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" onClick={this.props.actOnArea.bind(this, this.props.area)}>
            {this.props.area}
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
  
}

// Init
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <MyTableContainer />
    <MyTableContainer2 />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```